# How to know that open .docx file is "strict" or "transitional" programmatically in a c# class

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

Since there are two variants of a .docx file that is : "strict" or "transitional".
Is there a programmatic way to identify the variant of these .docx file ?

I have Add-in for MS Office Word and I need to allow only "transitional" and disallow/error for "strict".

So far I have attempted to get `wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Conformance`, but got null only from Conformance, Even I am not sure is it an ideal approach or not ...

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false))
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentConformance> Conformance = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Conformance;
if ("1".Equals(Conformance))
    {
    //throw exception
    }

}
```

Comment: If `conformance` isn't present, it's transitional. You can also check the namespaces. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642803/any-way-to-tell-if-an-arbitrary-docx-file-is-in-the-strict-office-open-xml-form, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/54d75b2c-3605-40c1-b6f3-e2542fd8ed35/transitional-or-strict-format-?forum=oxmlsdk

Comment: Thanks for looking on this query.
But here I am using strict docx file, that I can verify by peeping into document.xml where I see  w:conformance="strict", but in code Conformance comes as null.
Also I am using Open-xml-sdk 2.5 for word processing, can that be the reason ?, will switching to latest open-sdk will help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StrictRelationshipFound property.

However, be aware that the property can only identify Strict conformance. Transitional conformance can be null, and in my testing even when setting a bool? data type, this will not accurately identify Transitional conformance, but maybe someone knows a solution to this.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false)
                        
bool strict = doc.StrictRelationshipFound;
doc.Close();

if (strict == true)
{
//throw exception
}
```